# Evaluate some arguments to macro immediately

Tags: elisp-macros, eval

I am trying to call a macro (defined somewhere else; I can't change it), but I want to evaluate some of the arguments *before* the macro is expanded.  Is this possible?

For example:

```elisp
(defmacro foo (&rest args)
  (mapcar (lambda (a) (message "arg: %s" a)) args) nil)

(foo b (+ 1 1) c)
;; Prints:
;;   arg: b
;;   arg: (+ 1 1)
;;   arg: c
;; But I want:
;;   arg: b
;;   arg: 2
;;   arg: c
```

The only way I've found so far is:

```elisp
(eval `(foo b ,(+ 1 1) c))
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: 1. There's no way to ask an existing macro to evaluate its arguments when you call it (not doing so is one of the key properties of a macro).  2. Your example macro expands to `nil` and would trigger those messages only at expansion-time, so... that's weird.

Comment: I agree that it's a bit weird.  For context, I'm messing around with Doom Emacs' [`doom!`](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/develop/init.example.el) macro, which I assume was written as such to avoid quoting all of its arguments.  I'm trying to make some of my included packages conditional based on whether I am configured for running at work, at home, etc., but `doom!` is interpreting my `(when ...)` forms as package declarations.  The `eval` trick above seems to hack around that.

Comment: How about `(let ((tmp (+ 1 1))) (foo b tmp c))`?

Answer (score 2):

This is completely doable.  Since a macro operates on lists, your parameters are similarly going to be a list.  You can check if any of the elements in the argument list are lists themselves, and evaluate them:

```elisp
(defmacro foo (&rest args)
  (mapcar
   #'(lambda (a)
       (message "arg: %s" (if (listp a) (eval a) a)))  ; Changed here...
   args)
  nil)
```

For clarity, I've added some spacing.  Now, when I run this:

```elisp
(foo b (+ 1 1) c)
```

... it shows:

```
arg: b
arg: 2
arg: c
```

Your addition example is trivial, and your real code is probably more complicated, so beware.  This makes the potential for some instability if you *want* to pass in a list for some parameter.  I suppose you could get even fancier, and *also* check if the `car` of the list is a function, and so on as needed.